# what is correct format for user name that is not part of domain

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows 10 "Server Manager", and a VM with windows server 2012.
I'm trying remote manage windows server, but server manager asks me username and password, neither local PC and PC both are not part of domain.
So what is correct format for username?

I've test following format non of them workd:
username@ipaddress
ipaddress@username
username@computername

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Login using remote server name and its registrated user. For example, I have a server `sr-si-s00` and `administrator` as user. So simply input of `sr-si-s00\administrator` or `.\administrator` logs me in.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a local username?

Try .\username

.\ will change the domain to the local computer name

Comment: yes i mean username, i've attempted .\username;  server manager says The name provided isn't properly formed account name

Answer (score 1):

Should be computername\username, as far as I see. 
If you have access to a VM console, login there, run cmd, type "whoami" and it will give you the complete user name including the computer name.

Answer (score 1):

The specific error `The name provided is not a properly formed account name` usually occurs when a SAMaccountname is expected but a User Principal Name (UPN) is provided instead.

You should use either `computername\username` or simply `username`